# Java regex find first char NOT in range of chars

Tags: java, regex

In my SQL Server there is a `PATINDEX` function. For example:

```
patindex('%[^A-Z,^a-z,^0-9,^\,^_]%', SqlInstanceName)
```

This returns the `string` index position of the first character that is NOT in A-Z, NOT in a-z, NOT in 0-9, NOT = '\' (backslash) and NOT = '_' (underscore).

I want to do the same in Java 1.6/1.7 using Regex or using any built-in Java library methods.

Comment: Remove the ","s you have there. `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can do:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\w\\\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input); // input is your String 

if (m.find())
   System.out.println(m.start()); // start position of your match
```

Comment: `\w` matches any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, +1.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all! 
Using above tips I wrote this Java code and it seems to work for me:

```
// start code fragment
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9_\\\\]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
if (matcher.find()) 
{
    inputString = matcher.group(1);
}
// end code fragment
```

Much appreciated!